# Magento Cookie Issue When Logging Into Customer Account

Tags: magento-1.7, cookie, nginx, customer

I have a server setup locally with Vagrant which is running nginx + php5-fpm + mysql + varnish. I've disabled varnish for now just to rule that out.

I've been having issues when trying to login into a customer account on the frontend - it redirects backs to the homepage. The domain is set as www.site.local. I can log in into the admin area fine.

It appears that when redirecting to a successful login, it's creating a new session but not updating the cookie.

When running it via Lynx on the server itself, the cookie is set to fine - the only difference I can see is that it's using 127.0.0.1 as the domain rather than www.site.local

I tried the suggestion on this article - http://www.novusweb.com/1340/e-commerce-technology/fix-for-passing-magento-session-ids - and it works, but I'd rather not have to modify code when there's likely something server-side that can be changed.

If you need any of the configurations of the server I can update the post.

Comment: I've not attempted disabling any modules but the site is currently running on a LAMP stack and it's not having this issue.

Comment: It is correct yes.

Comment: Well after all of that, the problem was due to the Aoe_Static module. For whatever reason, when passing in the sid when rendering the blocks, it was losing the session. When commenting that line out, it works.

Answer (score 2):

**Change the domain from 127.0.0.1 to something else, eg.** `site.local`

There are reported issues of cookie problems when using `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` (or any variations of the `loopback` adapter) as the domain name.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The domain is being set as site.local on the one that isn't allowing me to log in - the test I did on the server itself used 127.0.0.1 and did work. When I commented out the renewSession() function on the customer, it's worked fine.